# Allow traffic through 2 tunnels on pfsense

Tags: routing, pfsense, ipsec

I have a device X 192.168.60.123 on location A and a 3rdparty server 172.16.0.2 on location C .

There is a ipsectunnel between location A 192.168.60.0 and location B 192.168.1.0.
Then there is a ipsectunnel between location B 192.168.1.0 and location C 172.16.0.0

Sending ping from B to C working.
But I cannot ping from A to C ?

Firewall rules is all open on the ipsec tab.

In the firewall logs I also see all green.

Where am I missing something?

Comment: Problem is solved.